# Determining the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ on $x_0 = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I've attempted to determine the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$, centered on $x_0 = 1$. Here's what I have thus far:

$f(1) = 1$

$f'(1) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2}$

$f''(1) = -\frac{1}{4x^{3/2}} = -\frac{1}{4}$

$f^{(3)}(1) = \frac{3}{8x^{5/2}} = \frac{3}{8}$

$\vdots$

Trivially, the Taylor series is of the form:

$$1 + \frac{1}{2(1!)}(x-1) - \frac{1}{4(2!)}(x-1)^2 + \frac{3}{8(3!)}(x-1)^3 + \cdots$$

Notice that the denominators are of the form $2^n(n!)$. We also have an alternating term, $(-1)^{n+1}$

$$\to \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} = \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(x-1)^n}{2^n(n!)}$$

When I graph this, however, it doesn't seem to be a particularly nice approximation of $\sqrt{x}$ *anywhere*.

Comment: Your formula for the general term does not work for $n=3$ (and is not correct for higher $n$'s either). It should be $$
\frac{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{2} - 1} \right) \cdots \left( {\frac{1}{2} - n + 1} \right)}}{{n!}}(x - 1)^n.$$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Comment: Dulicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937085/taylor-polynomial-for-sqrt-x/3937133#3937133 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ using sigma notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732540)

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt x=x^{1/2}$. Then:

- $f'(x)=\frac12x^{-1/2}$;
- $f''(x)=-\frac1{2^2}x^{-3/2}$;
- $f^{(3)}(x)=\frac{3}{2^3}x^{-5/2}$;
- $f^{(4)}(x)=-\frac{3\times5}{2^4}x^{-5/2}$

and so on… So,$$n>1\implies f^{(n)}(1)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!}{2^n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

What do you worry about ? The four first terms that you computed do match the square root fairly closely.

[image]